# ROS Answers SE migration: Wall Follower

Tags: kobuki

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, i am a really new in coding. I would like to code a wall follower so that my kobuki is able to move along the wall. When i try to run the code, kobuki is not moving. Can anyone help me out here please? Thanks alot.

```
#include "ros/ros.h"
#include "sensor_msgs/LaserScan.h"
#include "hokuyo/hokuyo.h"
#include "std_msgs/String.h"
#include <geometry_msgs/Twist.h>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;
float range[555], hit[555];

int z = 0;
void scanCallback(const sensor_msgs::LaserScan::ConstPtr& scan_msg)
{ 
  cout << z; z++;
/** this is to verify whether i am able to obtain the data i need*/
  ROS_INFO("I see: %u", scan_msg->header.seq);
  ROS_INFO("I see: %f", scan_msg->angle_min);
  ROS_INFO("I see: %f", scan_msg->time_increment);
    for (int y=150; y<=155; y++)
        {
    ROS_INFO("I see: %f", scan_msg->ranges[y]); 
    }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  ros::init(argc, argv, "wall_listener");
  ros::NodeHandle n;

  ros::Subscriber sub = n.subscribe("scan", 1000, scanCallback);

  ros::Publisher cmd_vel = n.advertise<geometry_msgs::Twist>("cmd_vel", 1000);

    for (int y=150; y<=1406; y++)
        {
    geometry_msgs::Twist move_cmd;
        move_cmd.angular.z = 0.2;
    move_cmd.linear.x = 0.5;
    cmd_vel.publish(move_cmd);  
    }

  ros::spin();

  return 0;
}
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/107566/wall-follower/) by [chao](https://answers.ros.org/users/9591/chao/) on ROS Answers with karma: 153 on 2013-12-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello chao,

I'm not 100% sure but my guess is that you get so many scan messages that you cannot publish anything (your node processes the callback function all the time).

To verify that you should use the command:

```
rostopic echo /cmd_vel
```

in your console. If you don't see any messages published to that topic, then it is obvious that you cannot publish. [rostopic](http://wiki.ros.org/rostopic)

Try doing this:

```
//#include ...    
ros::Publisher cmd_vel;
int z = 0;
void scanCallback(const sensor_msgs::LaserScan::ConstPtr& scan_msg)
{ 
    //cout << z; z++;
    /** this is to verify whether i am able to obtain the data i need*/
    ROS_INFO("I see: %u", scan_msg->header.seq);
    ROS_INFO("I see: %f", scan_msg->angle_min);
    ROS_INFO("I see: %f", scan_msg->time_increment);
    for (int y=150; y<=155; y++)
    {
    ROS_INFO("I see: %f", scan_msg->ranges[y]); 
    }

    for (int y=150; y<=1406; y++)
    {
        geometry_msgs::Twist move_cmd;
        move_cmd.angular.z = 0.2;
        move_cmd.linear.x = 0.5;
        cmd_vel.publish(move_cmd);
    }

}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    ros::init(argc, argv, "wall_listener");
    ros::NodeHandle n;

    ros::Subscriber sub = n.subscribe("/scan", 1000, scanCallback);

    cmd_vel = n.advertise<geometry_msgs::Twist>("/cmd_vel", 1000);

    ros::spin();

    return 0;
}
```

This is not the best programming practice. Your code needs to be organized a lot, however; it makes more sense to me this way and hopefully, you can understand the logic more easily. Now it says in your callback function that if you get a message from your laser,if you see anything, then publish cmd_vel commands.

---

Originally posted by [yigit](https://answers.ros.org/users/2389/yigit/) with karma: 796 on 2013-12-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [chao](https://answers.ros.org/users/9591/chao/) on 2013-12-06**:
Hi Yigit, it works i think. I have tried it on arbotix simulator and robot starts moving! Thanks alot :)

**Comment by [yigit](https://answers.ros.org/users/2389/yigit/) on 2013-12-06**:
You are welcome. Glad I could help.